# How to write multiple parameters in a controller in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make like `www.example.com/categories/{1}/{100}/`

{1} is a selection of category

{100} is a selection of subcategory

I made routes.php like this,

```
Route::get('/categories/{categoryId}/{subcategoryId}', ['as'=>'subcategory.post','uses'=>'AdminSubCategoriesController@subcategory']);
```

I am not sure how to set up controller at AdminSubCategoriesController@subcategory

```
public function subcategory($categoryId, $subcategoryId) 
{

    // I am not sure how to write here.

    // $category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);

    // $subcategories = SubCategory::findOrFail($subcategoryId);

    // $posts =        

    return view('subcategory', compact('$category','$subcategories'));

}
```

I want display only posts which related to `{1}/{100}` in a view.

Comment: you have get category and subcategoryid at adminSubCategoriesController..?

Comment: show us your relations and database schema, that question is not related to your controller and router

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a join query to get these posts back. I dont know what your schema looks like but here is an example

```
  $posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->join('categories', 'category.id', '=', 'posts.id')
                ->join('subcategories', 'subcategory.id', '=', 'category.id')
                ->select('posts.*')
                ->get();

return view('subcategory', compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Category:

```
<?php

namespace app;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {

    public function subcategories() {
        return $this->hasMany('app\Subcategory', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

Subcategory:

```
<?php

namespace app;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model {

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Category', 'category_id');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return Post::all()->where('subcategory_id', $this->id)->get();
    }

}
```

Using Eloquent relationships you'll need to adapt this to your controller passing your ids.